# How do I choose which calendar a meeting request is saved to?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

My office uses meeting requests to keep everyone aware of other's anticipated time out of the office. These meeting requests clutter up my calendar. I created a separate calendar in my mailbox just for these meeting requests. When accepting a meeting request is it possible to choose which calendar the request is saved to? Specifically I am using Outlook 2007 with Exchange.